# What UML diagram should I use to show a platform's architecture?

Tags: architecture, uml, diagrams, sequence-diagram

I have been learning UML and have a basic understanding now, but I keep seeing these sort of high level architecture diagrams. Here's one from Microsoft:

[image]

<sub>Source: [A bad picture is worth a thousand long discussions.](http://dougseven.com/2011/09/15/a-bad-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-long-discussions/)</sub>

Is this a UML diagram? Are there any rules to follow for creating these types of diagrams?

I would like to represent something similar, i.e. the realtionship between different installed systems / APIs... i.e. Platform architecture.

Comment: That's not an UML diagram.

Comment: So what is it exactly, i see lots of them around, I would like to learn more about them.

Comment: The blog post you linked to has a name for the diagram, it calls it a [marketecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchitecture) diagram. Seems like a perfectly good name for it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The more appropriate UML diagram to depict a platform's architecture is a [component diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram). If you want to go a level lower, then you'd also need to draw one or more [package diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_diagram), and perhaps even a [deployment diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram).

The diagram you linked to is not a UML diagram, it's a ["marchitecture / marketecture" diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchitecture). It's not really supposed to be technically accurate, its main purpose is to look good on a presentation slide. You can of course chose to go with such a diagram instead of a more formal UML diagram, however there aren't any concrete rules on how to draw them. It should convey a basic idea of your components and how they work together, and... look good ;)